# Как понять работу свойства background-position дисциплины css

Tags: html, css, background

Изучаю css и добрался до темы оформления, а именно до свойства background-position.
Столкнулся с непониманием работы данного свойства. Начну попорядку. Имеется блок размерами 500x400 px, внутри которого в качестве фона находится картинка. Она имеет размеры 200x200 px. При значении center у вышеуказанного свойства картинка в аккурат располагается по цетру вышеупомянутого блока. Тот же эффект достигается когда вместо слова center используются 50%. Здесь всё логично и не вызывает вопросов. И в начале при данном раскладе складывается впечатление что расположение картинки расчитывается так 400px * 50% = 200px. 200px от верхней края блока до центра картинки. Нетрудно вычислить растояние от верхнего края блока до верхнего края картинки оно будет равняться растоянию до центра картинки(равно центра блока) минус половина высоты картинки т.е.: 200px - 100px = 100px.[image: screen1] Всё элементарно. Математика уровня начальных классов. Но такое представление работает до тех пор пока не меняешь 50% сначало на 40% потом на 30% и вот когда доходишь до 20% и считаешь с этими значениями получаешь полный абсурд. Итак по выше указанной схеме:
400px * 20% = 80px(расстояние до центра картинки). Уже что-то не то, не правда ли?! Идём дальше посчитаем расстояние от верхнего края блока до верхнего края картинки. 80px - 100px = -20px. Т.е. получается наша картинка должна выйти за верхний край блока. Но что-то я этого не вижу.[image: screen2] Вышеописанные рассуждения поселили в мой разум зерно сомнения. Я отошёл от компьютера взял лист бумаги в клетку и начал рисовать. Но на бумаге появлялся тот же абсурд! Тогда меня посетила одна гениальная мысль: Значит при позиционировании вычисление расстояния производиться не использованием высоты блока, а с использованием высоты картинки и точкой отсчёта является любая из множества верхней стороны картинки. Сейчас поясню. 200px(высота картинки) * 50% = 100px. Что собственно и видно на первой картинке. Если мы также возьмём 20% то получим 200px * 20% = 40px, что опять же похоже на правду, судя по второму скриншоту. И казалось бы всё секрет свойства раскрыт и можно идти дальше. Если бы не одно НО. Такие рассуждения натолкнули меня на мысль, что если это работает с одной картинкой таких размеров, то это должно работать и с картинками других размеров. Для примера я взял другую картику размерами 300x300 px. [image: screen3] Далее по получившейся у меня схеме 300px(высота картинки) * 50% = 150px, что уже вызывает большие сомнения т.к. невооруженным глазом видно что на первом скриншоте видно что растояние от верхнего края блока до верхнего края картинки больше, нежели чем на третьем. Значит и вторая схема потерпела неудачу. Из всех проведенных исследований возникает логичный вопрос как это всё на самом деле разуметь. У меня всегда была в школе твёрдая четверка по геометрии. Проделав все эти логичные рассуждения напрашивается 2 вывода: Либо я нахрен забыл всю геометрию за 5-й класс(что очень и очень сомнительно), либо данноё свойство разрабатывал какой-то гуманитарий-извращенец, раз я человек изучивший 2 ЯП (js и php) никак не могу въехать в эту "логику" и вместо того чтобы продолжать дальше разбор тем из данной дисциплины уже 1,5 часа пишу этот вопрос и час до этого потратил на выяснение данного вопроса. Есть кто из вас разобрался с этим вопросом, будьте добры напишите формулу. Самому мне её выводить уже мягко говоря наскучило. Прикладываю скрины вёрстки: [image: html][image: css]

Comment: добавь твою разметку кодом, либо [сниппетом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4619/186999) а не картинкой

Comment: вот [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position#regarding_percentages) расписано, как считаются проценты

Comment: Я бы добавил код текстом, если бы не потратил на вопрос 2 с лишним часа. В редакторе эту разметку при такой необходимости можно сверстать за 5 минут максимум, здесь же вставлять код - та ещё мука!

Comment: здесь есть встроенный редактор, и ты мог точно так же _сверстать за 5 минут максимум_, но при этом зачем-то потратил два часа непонятно на что и в итоге плюхнул картинки, в которых только кусок твоего кода, причем неизвестно, насколько полон этот кусок, возможно твоя проблема была в совсем другой части твоего кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Процент считается от значения размер_блока-размер_картинки (для ширины и высоты), расстояние устанавливается до левого верхнего угла картинки
В примере размеры картинки 50x50, размер блоков 100x100. В первом блоке картинка прижата в правый нижний угол, потому что 100-50=50 и 100% от 50 это 50. Во втором блоке 1% от 50 это 0.5, но полпикселя отобразить нельзя, потому отступы округляются до 1 пикселя.

```css
.demo {
  border: 1px solid darkred;
  margin: 2px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIAAAAyAQMAAAAk8RryAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJNAAB6JgAAgIQAAPoAAACA6AAAdTAAAOpgAAA6mAAAF3CculE8AAAABlBMVEUAgID////5Zpl0AAAAAWJLR0QB/wIt3gAAAAd0SU1FB+YHBg8COxPjHWgAAAAOSURBVBjTY2AYBYMJAAABkAABxZvbSQAAACV0RVh0ZGF0ZTpjcmVhdGUAMjAyMi0wNy0wNlQxNTowMjo1OSswMDowMGLOhDIAAAAldEVYdGRhdGU6bW9kaWZ5ADIwMjItMDctMDZUMTU6MDI6NTkrMDA6MDATkzyOAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);
}

#first {
  background-position: 100% 100%;
}

#second {
  background-position: 1% 1%;
}
```

```html
<div id="first" class="demo">
</div>
<div id="second" class="demo">
</div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, приятель. Грамотно всё объяснил. Поставил обоим картинкам по 20% и когда у второй увидел меньшее расстояние всё стало ясно как 2x2. Сам себе удивляюсь почему я не дошёл до столь логичного и простого решения. Зелёного тебе цвета по жизни!